# Construct an N input OR Gate. An OR Gate returns 0 if all its inputs are 0, otherwise 1 using java

Tags: java, loops, variables

**Exact question**http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=1335

> Construct an N input OR Gate. An OR Gate returns 0 if all its inputs
> are 0, otherwise 1.

- Input:
- 3 //these are testcases
- 2 //these  are number of inputs
- 1 1 //these are inputs
- 3 //these
- 0 0 0
- 4
- 1 1 1 0
- > output: 1 //o/p for 1st case
- 0 //o/p for second case
- 1

**this code is causing run time error**

> errors such as Scanner java:907,java:1530,java:2160

```
    class GFG {
      
            static int or(int a[] , int n , int x){
               for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
               {
                   if(x==0)
                      return 0;
               }
                 return 1;
        }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[100];
        int x= 0;
        Scanner in  =new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        while(t>0){
            int n = in.nextInt();
            for(int i =0; i<n;i++){
               a[i] = in.nextInt();
               x =x+(a[i]|a[i+1]);
            }
               System.out.println(or(a,n,x));
               t--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You ask for an OR gate, but your method is called XOR. Furthermore, you have two other arguments to the method that are unexplained.

Comment: sorry for naming it xor sir but I want to know that how my two arguments are unexplained .Sorry I know I asking silly questions but I am beginner I know I am not of ur level but I just want to learn.

Comment: u can find this code here: http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/CLiX3K

Answer (score 0):

Well your code works for the most part but:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(x == 0)
        return 0;
}
return 1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(x == 0) return 0; else return 1;
```

What you want is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(a[i] == 0)
        return 0;
}
return 1;
```

In fact you could eliminate `x` altogether, but if you wanted to use `x` it wouldn't be necessary to store the numbers in `a`.

*Version without array*:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int x = 0; // assume x is 0.
    Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    while(t > 0) {
        int n = in.nextInt();
        x = 0; // reinitialise x each time.
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // if and only if all inputs are 0 will x be 0.
            // if any input is 1 -> x | 1 is 1 no matter what x. So the result will be 1.
            x = x | in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(x);
        t--;
    }
    in.close();
}
```

The input dialog box:

[image: Location of input dialog box]

You can use the sample input provided by the site.

Comment: but where did you or a[i] and a[i+1]

Comment: basically I used variable x to store value a[i]|a[I+1]

Comment: @user3427015 no. you didn't.

Comment: Well in your code you're doing the same job twice... Let me explain: in your `or` function you iterate over the array looking for a zero value, if it's there that means you should return 0. You are trying to do the exact same thing when you do `x = x + a[i] | a[i+1]` so if you used the `x` variable you wouldn't need the array `a` in the first place.

Comment: thanks a lot sir for ur help...But I am really sorry I tried ur code and it is showing same error here is the link:
http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/hiEdzc